# Integrating Solana Pay with Rust Code

Tags: anchor, rust, solana-pay

Is it possible to integrate **Solana Pay** with a program written in Rust + Anchor?
I have functions written in my Rust Program code, and I want users to scan a QR code and interact with those functions.
Can Solana Pay be used to make RPC calls is all I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can Solana Pay be used to make RPC calls is all I am asking.

Yes, if by "make RPC calls" you mean "send any kind of transaction". Solana Pay [transaction requests](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/master/SPEC.md#specification-transaction-request) can be used to create any kind of transaction on Solana. Therefore, you can

1. [Create an API](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/master/point-of-sale/src/server/api/index.ts#L31) that follows this spec, returning a transaction with instruction(s) to your program(s).
2. [Encode a URL](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/a3ec783a2e4df9b5587aee923817fd064e0b8d56/core/src/encodeURL.ts#L45) that follows this spec, targeting your API.
3. [Create a QR code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/a3ec783a2e4df9b5587aee923817fd064e0b8d56/core/src/createQR.ts#L25) that encodes the link.
4. Scan the QR code with [a wallet app](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay#supporting-wallets) that supports transaction requests. Phantom, Solflare, and Glow support them today, Slope is waiting on app store review.

Solana Pay cannot instruct a wallet to make arbitrary RPC calls, but it can instruct a wallet to send arbitrary transactions.

Comment: what could you possibly know about Solana Pay

Comment: Is there any implementation example of how to implement this? There seems to have nothing related to this into the Solana docs nor in the Anchor ones

Answer (score 4):

You can use any transaction (any sequence of instructions to any programs, including your own) with transaction requests: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/master/SPEC.md#specification-transaction-request

You'd basically need to write an API that takes a public key of the user who scanned as input, and outputs a serialized transaction, and then you can encode the URL of that API in the QR code.

You'd encode the URL by passing [TransactionRequestURLFields](https://docs.solanapay.com/api/core/interface/TransactionRequestURLFields) to [encodeURL](https://docs.solanapay.com/api/core/function/encodeURL). Here's an example: https://github.com/pointer-gg/solana-pay-tutorial/blob/5-coupon-v2/pages/shop/checkout.tsx#L59

Answer (score 0):

SolanaPay's `[createTransfer][1]` function returns a transaction of type `Transaction`.

Using Anchor's methods builder you should be able to construct an array of transactions, including the `createTransfer` transaction, and pass to `sendAndConfirm` method of the `AnchorProvider`.